# Entities drop when switching between VR mode

Tags: aframe, google-cardboard, webvr

I notice that objects drop when switching to VR mode (i.e. the cardboard glasses icon) on a phone or tablet. (verified on three different android devices)

E.g. - In below example - when entering VR, the sphere drops (about 1 on coordinates). Then exiting VR, sphere is still dropped. Repeating continues to drop the object lower each time.

Is there a way to prevent this?

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene antialias="true">
    <a-sky src="static/home/hawaii.jpg"></a-sky>
    <a-entity camera look-controls></a-entity>
    <a-sphere color="red" radius="1" position="2 0 -5"></a-sphere>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: This is a known bug. Try with master branch: https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-master.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: `<a-camera user-height="0">`

Answer (score 0):

In VR the camera tries to be at height 1.5. I'm guessing that the camera is shifting up when you enter VR, making it look like the sphere is going down.  Is there a reason you **don't** want it to shift to the VR position when entering VR?